# How to add multiple layers on Mapbox Android?

Tags: java, android-studio, mapbox, layer, mapbox-android

Right now I have three layers on my app and have a button for each of them. Each of the button toggles the designated layer, so when you want to show or hide the layer, you just need to click the button. However, this can be super inefficient and won't work if I wanted to have 10 layers. That means I will need to have 10 buttons - one button for each layer. Is there any efficient way to do this?

I don't want to end up having 10 buttons on my app just to show and hide each layer. Is there a way you can do a dropdown menu or something like this on Mapbox Android? I'm, of course, using Android Studio to code my app. For a reference, I used [this site](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/styles/ShowHideLayersActivity.java) to implement showing and hiding my layers.